# How to create a dotted line in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, line-art

How can I create a dotted swirly line like the example below in illustrator? I would like to create a loop dotted line.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on **stroke** (highlighted). one drop-down will appear. you can play with options.
[image]

Comment: thank you :) helped me in a panic moment.

Answer (score 6):

Create the line using the pen tool. Then in the 'Appearance' panel, click 'Stroke'. A bunch of options will appear. Play around with the 'Dashed Line' section to adjust the length of your dots/dashes on your line.

Comment: Right now you selected brush options.